# Is there any C standard function to pass a value "1" to all (%s)

Tags: c++, c

I just want to know whether any C (or C++) standard function to pass a value "1" to all (%s).

```
sprintf(buffer, "record_id(%s)record_num(%s)record_val (%s"), "1"));
```

instead of passing like and duplicating "1":

```
sprintf(query_buffer, "record_id(%s)record_num(%s)record_val (%s"), "1", "1", "1"));
```

Comment: No. And you need to know that C and C++ are different languages. And I don't see why you can't just hardcode this string.

Comment: Some libraries has positional placeholder `"%1 %2 %1"` format (or similar) which avoids to duplicate input.

Comment: @Jarod42: Are you thinking of POSIX [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and the `%1$s` notation that could be used to reuse the first argument more than once?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I had in mind boost format or Qt (was tagged C++).

Comment: Would you appreciae an answer with `"1"` only once, but a placeholder to represent it for each `"%s"`? Useable as `sprintf( buffer, "record_id(%s)record_num(%s)record_val (%s"), one, one, one) );`. (No macro magic in volved.)

Comment: @Pi Adding a C++ tag to a C tagged question unfairly draws undesireable attention. Focusing the question on one language would be better, but cannot be done in an edit.

Comment: Your optimizing compiler is *really good* at constant folding and similar optimizations. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can format it like this;

```
sprintf( buffer, "record_id(%s)record_num(%1$s)record_val (%1$s"), "1") );
```

This is a POSIX extension of the [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) format string.  You can be use n$ to indicate the nth parameter in the list.

Comment: That's a POSIX extension to the [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
family of functions.  Often available, but not necessarily available everywhere.

Comment: and please explain me this  sprintf( buffer, "record_id(%s)record_num(%1$s)record_val (%1$s"), "1") ); what is this -> ( %1$s ) .how it works

Comment: @deepakmj: follow the link to the POSIX specification of `printf()` et al; you'll find the details there.  That's why I gave the link — so it could be followed.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is no C standard function for that.
As for C++ (since you say cpp function), I'm not sure but I higly doubt that it exist.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing in the standard. Also check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) for more information.

You will have to look for a library which does this.

For example, in C++ this could be boost:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
int main ()
{
    std::cout << boost::format("%1%.%1%.%2%") % 12 % 2014 << '\n';
}
```

which outputs `12.12.2014`

Answer (score 0):

No! But you can make your own function that receives a number string and puts it into the %s...